# Change a div position dynamically in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a (complex) toolbar panel which can be on top or bottom of a page (it's configurable). Is there any way to **avoid** copy/paste the toolbar in bottom of the page?

Here is code in copy/paste way:

```
<div id="topToolbar" data-ng-show="configs.toolbarPosition=='TOP'">
    <!-- toolbar -->
</div>

<div>
    <!-- inner page contents -->
</div>

<div id="bottomToolbar" data-ng-show="configs.toolbarPosition=='BOTTOM'">
    <!-- exactly copy/pasted toolbar -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the tool bar html in separate file, and `include` where ever you need.

```
<ng-include src="'views/toolbar.html'"></ng-include>
```

Also if you needed add a controller for all functionality. This will help you to reuse your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can check how components are made
and make component <toolbar></toolbar>